# change array size

Tags: c#, arrays, size

Is it possible to change an array size after declaration?
If not, is there any alternative to arrays?
I do not want to create an array with a size of 1000, but I do not know the size of the array when I'm creating it.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No, try using a strongly typed [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead.

For example:

Instead of using

```
int[] myArray = new int[2];
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
```

You could do this:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(2);
```

Lists use arrays to store the data so you get the speed benefit of arrays with the convenience of a `LinkedList` by being able to add and remove items without worrying about having to *manually* change its size.

This doesn't mean an array's size (in this instance, a `List`) isn't changed though - hence the emphasis on the word manually.

As soon as your array hits its predefined size, the JIT will allocate a new array on the heap that is twice the size and copy your existing array across.

Comment: Yes by this way: string[] arr1 = new string[]{};
    Array.Resize(ref arr1, 7);

Answer (score 100):

You can use `Array.Resize()`, documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx).

But yeah, I agree with Corey, if you need a dynamically sized data structure, we have `List`s for that.

Important: `Array.Resize()` ***doesn't resize the array*** (the method name is misleading), it creates a new array and only replaces the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) you passed to the method.

An example:

```
var array1 = new byte[10];
var array2 = array1;
Array.Resize<byte>(ref array1, 20);

// Now:
// array1.Length is 20
// array2.Length is 10
// Two different arrays.
```

Comment: If Array.Resize() is just once at the beginning (and not multiple times during the program), is that more suitable than a List?

Comment: `List<T>` uses an Array behind the scenes, so there are very few reasons to use an Array in C#.  Lists can be initialized to a suitable size using this constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx.  But yes, if your heart is set on Arrays, it's better to resize them as infrequently as possible.

Comment: I thought List<T> uses a linked list or some data structure behind. So it uses array after all.

Comment: Be carefull, Array.Resize does not preserve your reference. Instead, it creates a new array of the required size.

Comment: Does this  resizing effect the optimization and complexity. I am using insertion sort, so when I add an element in the array, I increase the size and redo the insertion sort algorithm, so does it effect the program performance?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @shubhraj...  `Array.Resize` creates a new array of the specified size. The beginning of the new array is the same as the old array, and the additional space is filled with the default value for the Array's type (null for reference types)

Comment: Yes, I got ur answer on what the Array.Resize does. I am doing the same. I have an array &  filled with random number. I sort the array in ascending order using Insertion Sort Algorithm. Now I add another integer to the array, for doing this I use the solution you mentioned above. So it reallocates more memory space to the array. Does this effect the performance of the program during runtime? I need to optimize my code, so I'm confused whether to use List<int> or Array.Resize..Hope u got my point of what I am trying to explain..

Comment: `List<Int>` is using Array.Resize under the covers. It uses a generally (though not universally) optimal algorithm under the covers, wherein it doubles the size of the array each time that it grows it. Unless you are working on high performance realtime systems (high-speed trading or mechanical control systems for example) you should use `List<Int>` as it will be "good enough" and is more maintainable.

Comment: @ChrisShain so how can we delete old reference if it don't delete old reference ???

Comment: Assuming the old array is not rooted by anything it will be garbage collected

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible to resize an array. For example:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
// increase size to 10
Array.Resize(ref arr, 10);
// decrease size to 3
Array.Resize(ref arr, 3);
```

If you create an array with CreateInstance() method, the Resize() method is not working. For example:

```
// create an integer array with size of 5
var arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 5);
// this not work
Array.Resize(ref arr, 10);
```

The array size is not dynamic, even we can resize it. If you want a dynamic array, I think we can use generic List instead.

```
var list = new List<int>();
// add any item to the list
list.Add(5);
list.Add(8);
list.Add(12);
// we can remove it easily as well
list.Remove(5);
foreach(var item in list)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Array.Resize()` in .net 3.5 and higher.  This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.
(So you will need the memory available for both arrays as this probably uses `Array.Copy` under the covers)

Answer (score 6):

In C#, arrays cannot be resized dynamically.

- One approach is to use
  ***`System.Collections.ArrayList`*** instead
  of a ***`native array`***.
- Another (faster) solution is to
  re-allocate the array with a
  different size and to copy the
  contents of the old array to the new
  array.

  The generic function ***`resizeArray`*** (below) can be used to do that.

  ```
  public static System.Array ResizeArray (System.Array oldArray, int newSize)  
      {
        int oldSize = oldArray.Length;
        System.Type elementType = oldArray.GetType().GetElementType();
        System.Array newArray = System.Array.CreateInstance(elementType,newSize);

        int preserveLength = System.Math.Min(oldSize,newSize);

        if (preserveLength > 0)
        System.Array.Copy (oldArray,newArray,preserveLength);

       return newArray; 
    }  

   public static void Main ()  
         {
          int[] a = {1,2,3};
          a = (int[])ResizeArray(a,5);
          a[3] = 4;
          a[4] = 5;

          for (int i=0; i<a.Length; i++)
                System.Console.WriteLine (a[i]); 
          }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Use [System.Collections.Generic.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Use a `List<T>` instead. For instance, instead of an array of ints

```
private int[] _myIntegers = new int[1000];
```

use

```
private List<int> _myIntegers = new List<int>();
```

later

```
_myIntegers.Add(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Used this approach for array of bytes:

Initially:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
```

Whenever required (Need to provide original length for extending):

```
Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, bytes.Length + requiredSize);
```

Reset:

```
Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, 0);
```

***Typed List Method***

Initially:

```
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
```

Whenever required:

```
bytes.AddRange(new byte[length]);
```

Release/Clear:

```
bytes.Clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

In C#, `Array.Resize` is the simplest method to resize any array to new size, e.g.:

```
Array.Resize<LinkButton>(ref area, size);
```

Here, i want to resize the array size of LinkButton array:

`<LinkButton>` = specifies the array type
`ref area` = ref is a keyword and 'area' is the array name
`size` = new size array

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void HandleResizeArray()
    {
        int[] aa = new int[2];
        aa[0] = 0;
        aa[1] = 1;

        aa = MyResizeArray(aa);
        aa = MyResizeArray(aa);
    }

    private int[] MyResizeArray(int[] aa)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref aa, aa.GetUpperBound(0) + 2);
        aa[aa.GetUpperBound(0)] = aa.GetUpperBound(0);
        return aa;
    }
```

Comment: What do you do by doing UpperBound?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to get it back into an array I find it easiest to convert the `array` to a `list`, expand the list then convert it back to an `array`.

```
        string[] myArray = new string[1] {"Element One"};
        // Convert it to a list
        List<string> resizeList = myArray.ToList();
        // Add some elements
        resizeList.Add("Element Two");
        // Back to an array
        myArray = resizeList.ToArray();
        // myArray has grown to two elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a List (where T is any type or Object) when you want to add/remove data, since resizing arrays is expensive. You can read more about [Arrays considered somewhat harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/) whereas a List can be added to New records can be appended to the end. It adjusts its size as needed.

A List can be initalized in following ways

Using collection initializer.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>()
{
    "carrot",
    "fox",
    "explorer"
};
```

Using var keyword with collection initializer.

```
var list2 = new List<string>()
{
    "carrot",
    "fox",
    "explorer"
};
```

Using new array as parameter.

```
string[] array = { "carrot", "fox", "explorer" };
List<string> list3 = new List<string>(array);
```

Using capacity in constructor and assign.

```
List<string> list4 = new List<string>(3);
list4.Add(null); // Add empty references. (Not Recommended)
list4.Add(null);
list4.Add(null);
list4[0] = "carrot"; // Assign those references.
list4[1] = "fox";
list4[2] = "explorer";
```

Using Add method for each element.

```
List<string> list5 = new List<string>();
list5.Add("carrot");
list5.Add("fox");
list5.Add("explorer");
```

Thus for an Object List you can allocate and assign the properties of objects inline with the List initialization. Object initializers and collection initializers share similar syntax.

```
class Test
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize list with collection initializer.

```
List<Test> list1 = new List<Test>()
{
    new Test(){ A = 1, B = "Jessica"},
    new Test(){ A = 2, B = "Mandy"}
};
```

Initialize list with new objects.

```
List<Test> list2 = new List<Test>();
list2.Add(new Test() { A = 3, B = "Sarah" });
list2.Add(new Test() { A = 4, B = "Melanie" });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me to create a dynamic array from a class array.

```
var s = 0;
var songWriters = new SongWriterDetails[1];
foreach (var contributor in Contributors)
{
    Array.Resize(ref songWriters, s++);
    songWriters[s] = new SongWriterDetails();
    songWriters[s].DisplayName = contributor.Name;
    songWriters[s].PartyId = contributor.Id;
    s++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a generic List (System.Collections.Generic.List).

Answer (score -1):

In case you cannot use `Array.Reset` (the variable is not local) then `Concat` & `ToArray` helps:

```
anObject.anArray.Concat(new string[] { newArrayItem }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a way to increment the length of my array in a simple guessing game using while loops. The array was initialised with a length of 1. I used 'i' (initialised at 0) to  record the number of guesses in the current round of the loop. Line 2 displays the lowest score in the array. After incrementing the array position for the next round, I used Array.Resize() to extend the length of the array by i + 1. This way, the array length extends with each iteration of the loop.

```
arr[i] = guesses; 
Console.WriteLine("Best Score: {0}", arr.Min()); 
i++; 
Array.Resize(ref arr, i + 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Resize(ref int[] Arr, int k)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        newArray[i]=arr[i];            
    Arr=newArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to give a very different answer. Yes and you don't need lists or Array.Resize!! Example:

```
int[] arr = className.MethodName(arguments); \\ has size in ex. 10
arr = className.MethodName(newArguments); \\ now has a different size
```

your class methods can update the array size, no problem. In the code above replace the class name and method name and arguments accordingly.

Comment: This is reassigning the value of `arr` to something else, not actualy resizing the underlying array. the old array still exists.