# How to increase byte[] size at run time?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have to increase `byte[]`  array size at runtime.
How to increase byte[] array size at run time ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change array size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840802/change-array-size)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Why does no one seem to know **[Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)**:

```
 Array.Resize(ref myArray, 1024);
```

Simple as pie.

PS: _as per a comment on MSDN, apparently this was missing from the MSDN documentation in 3.0.

Comment: @Brian: thanks, I had copied the wrong link in the answer, sry

Comment: Note that this creates a new Array, if you have a reference to the old array somewhere, that array won't be updated.

Comment: +1 just to know this exists... however one could be pedantic and say that this doesn't actually change the size of the passed array.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo it DOES update the old array, that's why the `ref`

Comment: @Alex is right. But notice that it DOES copy and point to a new array.

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit It's a matter of semantics: is "the array" the variable or the memory it points to? This function does update the variable, but the memory it (used to) point to is still the same size. I'd say that the chunk of memory is the actual array so it's correct to say this function didn't actually resize the original array.

Answer (score 17):

You can't: arrays are fixed size.<sup>1</sup>

Either use a re-sizable collection (eg. `List<byte>`) or create a new larger array and copy the contents of the original array over.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) doesn't modify the passed array object: it creates a new array and copies the elements. It just saves you coding this yourself. The difference is important: other references to the old array will continue to see the old array.

Answer (score 7):

You could allocate a new array and copy the bytes over with [`Array.Copy(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx)

```
byte[] oldArr = new byte[1024];
byte[] newArr = new byte[oldArr.Length * 2];

System.Array.Copy(oldArr, newArr, oldArr.Length);

oldArr = newArr;
```

Comment: @jams: a temp is what you don't require [when using `Array.Resize`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017039/how-to-increase-byte-size-at-run-time/6017109#6017109) (grin)

Comment: @Everyone about `tmp` - I changed `tmp` to `oldArr` but forgot to change it in the method, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to increase it, why not start off with a `List<byte>` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

A array is of fixed size, and cannot be dynamically changed at runtime.

Your only option is to create a new array of the wanted size, and copy all bytes from the old array to the new one.

But why torture yourself with this instead of using `List<byte>` and simply adding or removing elements at will?

Answer (score -1):

if your byte array is used to collect data and grow with it, you can use the class:
System.IO.MemoryStream
([here link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-8.0) to microsoft class description)