# dynamically increase of the number of elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I'm trying to create a dynamic array which starts with 3 elements. I want to use addColumn to add an element to string[] name. But I guess the the addColumn function is not doing what I expected.What do I need to archieve that functionality? I guess I need saomething like "name.addElement()"?

```
class LogData
{
    private string[] name;
    private int numberOfColumns;

     public LogData()
     {
         name = new string[3];
         numberOfColumns = name.Length;    
     }

     public void addColumn()
     {
         name = new string[1];// Thats not working, after calling, the number of columns is still 3
     }

     public int getNumberofcolumns()
     {
         return numberOfColumns;
     }
}
```

I call in the main fucntion:

```
LogData logData = new LogData();

Console.Write(logData.getNumberofcolumns() + "\n");
logData.addColumn();
Console.Write(logData.getNumberofcolumns() + "\n");

Console.Write("done...\n\n");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is:

```
3
3
done...
```

Comment: Use a `List<>` if you want to add items. If you finally need an array use `list.ToArray()`.

Comment: Think about `List<string>` which offers everything you need automatically...

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840802/change-array-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you lloking for

```
  public void addColumn() {
    Array.Resize(ref name, name.Length + 1);
  }
```

But, IMHO, a better solution is to change `String[]` to `List<String>`:

```
  class LogData
  {
    private List<String> name = new List<String>();

    ...
    public void addColumn() {
      name.Add(null);
    }
```

Comment: does this function just add one element to the array?

Comment: @xy36: it *resizes* the array and in case items are *added* they will be `null`s

Comment: Thats nice. I assume all data in the "old" array will stay the same?

Comment: @xy36: yes, the old data will be preserved

Comment: Do I miss something? My compiler cant find the add-function.

Comment: @xy36: `Add` function is declared in `List<T>` only, so in case of `private List<String> name` you can use `Add` and in case of `private string[] name` - not

Answer (score 1):

Use `List<string>` instead of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You only assign the number of columns once, it doesn't get the length of the name whenever you call it, the whole field is pointless

```
 public int getNumberofcolumns()
 {
     return name.Length;
 }
```

Note: Of course, a list would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `List<string>` which offers you a ton of libraries for manipulating it, and it covers all your requirements. here's the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usage:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();

//adding an item
names.Add('YourString');
//getting the length
names.Count();
```