# How can I count the number of elements in an array?

Tags: c#

I have this array:

```
var categoryGroups = new[] {
    new CategoryGroupSource { Id = 1,  Name = "Conversation" },
    new CategoryGroupSource { Id = 2,  Name = "Business" },
    new CategoryGroupSource { Id = 3,  Name = "Education" }
};
```

I tried to do a count on this:

```
categoryGroups.Count
```

But it is giving me an error saying this will only work with a list. Can someone give me advice on this?

Note I am also doing this:

```
foreach (CategoryGroupSource categoryGroup in categoryGroups)
{
    db.Insert(categoryGroup);
}
```

Does the foreach work for arrays and lists?

Comment: Use `Length`, not `Count`

Comment: Answer could have been found easily on google/MSDN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `categoryGroups.Length` for the arrays

```
var categoryGroups = new[] {
            new CategoryGroupSource { Id = 1,  Name = "Conversation" },
            new CategoryGroupSource { Id = 2,  Name = "Business" },
            new CategoryGroupSource { Id = 3,  Name = "Education" }
        };

int count = categoryGroups.Length;
```

> Does the foreach work for arrays and lists?

Yes.

[Using foreach with Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw.aspx)

Comment: Pros and Cons using array for Generic<T>?

Comment: @Aizen Popular question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which

Answer (score 1):

You might have used

```
categoryGroups.Length
```

Every array has a Length. In the C# language we access the Length property on a non-null array. Length has no parentheses, as it is a property. It is read-only—you cannot assign Length.

And yes of-course `foreach` works for arrays and list. and if you wanted to see [Why List is better than Arrays you can read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40987538/3796048)

Answer (score 1):

foreach works of arrays and lists

For Counting no of element in array

change

```
categoryGroups.Count
```

to

```
categoryGroups.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, arrays and strings (which are technically special character arrays) have a `Length` property, and just about every other collection has a `Count` property for this counting elements.

In addition to this, the `System.Linq` namespace provides a `Count()` extension method for the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, which most collections implement.  So for an array you can also use `myArray.Count()`, if you're `using System.Linq;`.

Note that `Count()` is a method on arrays and any collection implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, while `Count` is a property of some collections.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` works with all types that implements `IEnumerable`.

You were not able to access `.count` property because it is available for List types, but you are using Array.

Answer (score 0):

I agree if you just want it to say the amount of values in the array you could just print the length value of the array.