# Can arrays be resized in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Just out of curiosity, coming from C background, I knew that Array cannot be resized.

However, while I see in C#, it's so easy to do like below

```
var arr = new int[] {1,2,4,6};
arr = new int[2];
```

Also, there is a method available

```
Array.Resize(ref arr, 10);
```

How is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Array.Resize.  allocates a new array. It then copies existing element values to the new array.

Comment: C++ has variable-length arrays too, `std::vector<T>`. The equivalent in .NET is `List<T>`, not arrays. In *both* languages, the data is stored in an internal buffer. When the buffer runs out, *both* languages will allocate a new larger buffer (array) and copy the data to it, discarding the older buffer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840802/change-array-size)

Comment: It's explained in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netcore-3.1 "This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one"

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but did you say that this code `arr = new int[2];` resizes the array? Edit: Okay, after reading the answers, it really seems you actually meant this, at least everyone understood it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These operations aren't resizing the array.  They're creating a new array of a new size.

Note in the first example that you call `new` twice.  So you're creating two arrays.

In the second example, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize) explains the same:

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be resized in C#.

Your first example assigns a *new* array to the variable `arr`, it doesn't resize the existing array.

Also `Array.Resize` is a misnomer: it actually creates a new array and copies the values.

The clue to that is with the `ref` keyword, which indicates that `Array.Resize` will be reassigning to `arr`.

Comment: Wondering why Array.Reszie() accepts parameter with ref keyword

Comment: @Kgn-web Because that passes `arr` by reference, so `Array.Resize` can reassign to that variable directly. Without `ref` it could only return the new array, which would have to be assigned manually e.g. `arr = Array.Resize(arr, 10)`.

Comment: Thanks! for explaination

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the Array class can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs).

This is the relevant portion:

```
T[] larray = array;                
if (larray == null) {
    array = new T[newSize];
    return;
}

if (larray.Length != newSize) {
    T[] newArray = new T[newSize];
    Array.Copy(larray, 0, newArray, 0,  larray.Length > newSize? newSize : larray.Length);
    array = newArray;
}
```

As you can see, it allocates a new array and then copies whatever it can from the existing array into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those examples actually creates a brand new array, copies the items one by one from the old to the new, and updates the reference.

If you have a collection where the size will change over time, you're almost always better off using a generic `List<T>`.