# Creating a highscore list in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, integer

I need to use arrays/lists for my assignment and thought of using one for my highscore list for my game in windows form.

Right now I'm using a regular int for my Score and I'm wondering how I can get this into an array for a highscore list on my highscore.cs

**Current code for score in game.cs**

```
int Score = 0; 
Scorelabel.Text ="score:" + score;
 if (Picturebox.Left < -180)
            {
                Picturebox.Left = 800;
                Score++;*
```

**Things I've tried:**

```
namespace Game
{
    public partial class Highscore : Form
    {
        public Highscore()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] Highscore = new int[10];
            for (int Score = 0; Score < 10; Score++)
            {
                textBox1.Text = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to make the initial score int an array. I would end up getting the error:*"Operator ++ cannot be applied to operand of type 'int[]'*

Also tried to get my int into an array but would get the error that I can't convert ints to arrays.

**What I want**

I want my scores  from the game.cs to show in a listbox on my highscore.cs that shows the top 10 scores descending from highest to lowest.

Comment: `Scorelabel.Text = $"score: {string.Join(", ", score.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(10))};"`

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried instead of just a description?

Comment: Without seeing what you tried before, I can't say for 100% what caused the errors other than assumptions. High score lists generally grow as more users play them, so an array wouldn't make much sense as they (at least in C#) have to have their size declared and modifying after the fact isn't really how they are meant to work. If you want to modify the size, I recommend working with a strongly typed list instead of an array. Try what you attempted before with the array and let us know if you still have issues.
Backup for my claims: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840802/change-array-size

Comment: `namespace Game
{
    public partial class HighscorePage : Form
    {
        public HighscorePagina()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] Highscore = new int[10];
            for (int Score = 0; Score < 10; Score++)
            {
                textBox1.Text = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: This is the code that I tried earlier today, but got the error : 
 Cannot Implicitly convert type to string

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you've got 20 players and each one got some score.

As you decided to create an array of `int`s to store all scores, so do I:

```
int[] scores = new int[20];
```

For example, I fill that array with random unique scores from 10 to 100. You fill in your way:

```
int[] scores = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
{
    int score = 0;

    // This loop used to generate new random int until it wouldn't be unique (wouldn't exist in array)
    while (score == 0 || scores.Contains(score))
        score = rnd.Next(10, 100);

    scores[i] = score;

    lblAllScores.Text += "Player #" + (i + 1) + " score: " + scores[i] + "\n";
}
```

I append each score and Player # (as *number of iteration + 1*) to some `Label` on `Form` to show all players and their scores. Something like this:

[image]

Now you (and I) want take top 10 scores (obviously in *descending order*, from highest to lowest). Here the keywords are **Take** and **Descending order**. In C# through `System.Linq` namespace provided such pretty extension methods like `Take` and `OrderByDescending`. And seems they can give us desired result if we use it properly.

I (and you) creating a new array of `int`s to store only Top 10 Scores. Then a take initial array `scores` and use `OrderByDescending` method to sort values in it from highest to lowest. `(x => x)` provided as selector to determine key by which method should order values - in our case by value itself. And then I use `Take(10)` method to take first 10 scored from that sorted array - this is our Top 10 Scores:

```
int[] top10Scores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(10).ToArray();
```

And all I need to do - put this into `Form`, which I can do by simple iteration on `top10Scores` array with `for` loop. But I (and probably you) want to know *what* Player has that score. Upper we use *(index of array + 1)* as *Player Number*. And we know that scores are *unique* for each Player. Than now we can take the score value from `top10Scores` array and try to find its index in source `scores` array with `Array.FindIndex` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < top10Scores.Length; i++)
{
    int playerNumber = Array.FindIndex(scores, score => score == top10Scores[i]) + 1;
    lblTop10Scores.Text += "Player #" + playerNumber + " score: " + top10Scores[i] + "\n";
}
```

And at our Form we have this:

[image]

Complete code:

```
private void ScorePlayers()
{
    int[] scores = new int[20];
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
    {
        int score = 0;

        while (score == 0 || scores.Contains(score))
            score = rnd.Next(10, 100);

        scores[i] = score;

        lblAllScores.Text += "Player #" + (i + 1) + " score: " + scores[i] + "\n";
    }

    int[] top10Scores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(10).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < top10Scores.Length; i++)
    {
        int playerNumber = Array.FindIndex(scores, score => score == top10Scores[i]) + 1;
        lblTop10Scores.Text += "Player #" + playerNumber + " score: " + top10Scores[i] + "\n";
    }
}
```

Please note, that this is **only** a sketch and example to demonstrate how to use `OrderByDescending` and `Take` extension methods to get first 10 elements of sorted from highest to lowest value collection. In real application you probably will have at least simple `Dictionary<string, int>`, where would be stored player name (as `string`) and his score (as `int`). Or, more likely, it would be a model class called `Player` with `Name` and `Score` properties and each `Player` would be stored in some `List<Player>`:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Hope you can find your solution and this example would be helpful for you.